# How to conditionally install third party applications in WiX Bundle

Tags: wix

I have a WiX installer and I have created a bootstrapper project for the same in order to install my pre requisites. However, I would like pre-requisites to only get installed if they are not already there on the system. Is it possible to add such a condition to my code?

This is the code I have right now, where in it installs my application. But I would like to add the conditions to it.

```
<Fragment>
        <PackageGroup Id="OpenTAP">
            <ExePackage
              SourceFile="..\..\..\External\Prerequisites\OpenTAP\ITS_OpenTap.9.18.5_Installer.exe"
              DetectCondition="ExeDetectedVariable"
              InstallCommand="/q /ACTION=Install"
              RepairCommand="/q ACTION=Repair /hideconsole"
              UninstallCommand="/q ACTION=Uninstall /hideconsole" />
        </PackageGroup>
    </Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ExePackage` will only install if the `DetectCondition` is false. So, as long as you are setting the `ExeDetectedVariable` correctly then Burn will behave exactly as you desire.